# Laravel: Google Fonts @import +@font-face stopped loading on live server but always loads on Local Server

Tags: laravel, fonts

I have imported `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400,500,600,700|Merriweather:300,300i,400,400i&amp;display=swap');`
inside my style.css but I get this error on deployment to the Live server

> Access to URI denied. The style sheet could not be loaded due to
> access restrictions.

**1st solution**
I added @font-face and loaded the files in my public/frontassets/fonts and called them from my style sheet.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Hind'!important;
  src:  url('../fonts/Hind-Medium.ttf');
  src:  url('../fonts/Hind-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/Hind-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/Hind-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/Hind-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../hind-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../hind-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: normal;
```

The fonts fail to load and are overlooked when the stylesheet is loaded.

**solution 2:**
I added

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    .eot
AddType application/x-font-opentype      .otf
AddType image/svg+xml                    .svg
AddType application/x-font-ttf           .ttf
AddType application/font-woff            .woff
AddType application/font-woff2           .woff2



<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".(eot|otf|svg|ttf|woff|woff2?)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

in my htaccess file.
Still no change in the fonts.

Note I am running the live from a subdomain

Thank you for your assistance.

Fonts do not load on inspection

[image: Image after inspection @font-face do not load]

Here is how they appear in my style.css

`style.css`

```
            Fonts
====================================================================

 ***/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400,500,600,700|Merriweather:300,300i,400,400i&amp;display=swap');

/*
font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
*/

@import url('owl.css');
@import url('fontawesome-all.css');
@import url('stroke-gap-icons.css');
@import url('flaticon.css');
@import url('animate.css');
@import url('jquery-ui.css');
@import url('jquery.fancybox.min.css');
@import url('scrollbar.css');
@import url('hover.css');
@import url('custom-animate.css');


@font-face {
  font-family: 'Hind'!important;
  src:  url('../fonts/Hind-Medium.ttf');
  src:  url('../fonts/Hind-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/Hind-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/Hind-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/Hind-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../hind-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../hind-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: normal;


}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Signature';
  src:  url('../fonts/JustSignatureRegularea59.eot?lsn0el');
  src:  url('../fonts/JustSignatureRegularea59.eot?lsn0el#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/JustSignatureRegularea59.ttf?lsn0el') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/JustSignatureRegularea59.woff?lsn0el') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/JustSignatureRegularea59.svg?lsn0el#Signature') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

Comment: What browser is this happening with? Only in Firefox?

Comment: all browsers, chrome, IE, firefox

Comment: In solution 1 when you say the fonts fail to load, what is the failiure there?

Comment: They are overlooked, when you inspect the browser the code doesn't even load, check the question again I have updated a snippet of my style.css after it loads and after inspection, you will notice that they do appear.

Comment: The error message cited in the question isn’t a CORS error, and https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400,500,600,700|Merriweather:300,300i,400,400i&amp;display=swap is served with an `access-control-allow-origin: *` response header. And whatever changes are made to the CORS config for a server other than  `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css` isn’t gonna affect loading of fonts from `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css`. And the error says *“The **style sheet** could not be loaded due to access restrictions”* — so  it’s not an error about fonts anyway, but instead about some stylesheet

Comment: would you know the reason why that particular @font-face won't load? It's completely overlooked When the project is live?..  is there another possible explanation. I am still stuck .